# Web Scraping Yahoo Finance Recommendation Rating

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am trying to web scrape Yahoo's Finance Recommendation Rating using BeautifulSoup but it keeps returning 'None'.
E.g. Recommendation Rating for AAPL is '2'
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL

Please advise. Thank you!

Below is the code:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tickers = ['AAPL']
url = 'https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s/profile?p=%s'%(ticker, ticker)
print(url)
response = get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

#yf_rec refers to yahoo finance recommendation

try:
    yf_rec = html_soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'B(8px) Pos(a) C(white) Py(2px) Px(0) Ta(c) Bdrs(3px) Trstf(eio) Trsde(0.5) Arrow South Bdtc(i)::a Fw(b) Bgc($buy) Bdtc($buy)'}).text.strip()
except:
    pass
```

print(yf_rec)

Comment: page is dynamic is generated with JavaScript. Sometimes you can find the data within the script tags or through an api, which I did not see for either case. Your next option then would be to use Selenium to have the page render first, then you can parse the html

Comment: hi there - i run this on MX-Linux and on ATOM and i get back the following results `Python - bs_yahoo_finance.py:17
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/.atom/python/examples/bs_yahoo_finance.py", line 5, in <module>
    url = 'https://sg.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s/profile?p=%s'%(ticker, ticker)
NameError: name 'ticker' is not defined
[Finished in 0.415s]` . why is this so here ?

Comment: You can try a package called [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery).  Once installed, you can get current recommendation, as well as previous three months, with the following code:  `Ticker('aapl').recommendation_trend`